# Unable to assign button click to buttons in anchor tag angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

here i am trying to click the button under the anchor tag but when i try to click anchor tag is clicked instead button below is my code

```
<mat-nav-list *ngFor="let data of List;let i = index" >
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="[ '/transg',data.Id]">
        <span matLine>{{data.Name}}</span>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit($event)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="onRemove($event)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </a>

      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

i tried

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation();onEdit($event)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Try to prepend `$event.stopPropagation()` on  your `onEdit` function. When you click the button, `onEdit` is called, and the event is propagated to all ancestors, such as the link wrapping. This should fix the problem.

Comment: u mean  onedit(){  $event.stopPropagation()}

Comment: Exactly. You can also add a `$event.preventDefault()` as well.

Comment: please check the updated question@Treast

Comment: Ok two things: on your previous anwser, the function is named `onEditStation` but `onEdit` on the HTML. Mistake or wrong function ? I find another solution, just add this `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS of the link.

Comment: `(click)="$event.preventDefault();$event.stopPropagation();onEdit($event)"` should be enough here

Comment: when i tried pointe events not the router link stopped working and it is onEdit only

Comment: @yurzui i follwed ur approach too when i click on icon still it is redirected to page instead of button click

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vufgsj?file=src/app/sidenav-overview-example.html

Comment: I tried it didnt work